# how to display values from SQL database when an IP address is matched

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

..What Method I'm using..
I'm creating UWP app connecting to a SQL Server database via WebService.

..What I need help with..
I want to display values from the Database when the IP address matches the PC the App is run on.

..What I have so far..
Right now I have the code beyond to grab PC's local HostName show below. Might need to move it to Appx, have not decided. I also have Values displaying on the View called DevicePage. The DevicePageViewModel is making the call to the WebService

CodeBeyond>>

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HostName localHostName in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
        {
            if (localHostName.IPInformation != null)
            {
                if (localHostName.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)

                    capturedHostName.Text = localHostName.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel>>

```
        var uriD = new Uri("http://localhost:2463/api/Devices");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        try
        {
            var JsonResponseD = await client.GetStringAsync(uriD);
            var devicesResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Device>>(JsonResponseD);

            Devices = devicesResult;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Unable to Access WebService at this Time!");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }

        client.Dispose();
```

EntityFramework Model>>

```
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int HostName { get; set; }
    public string RouterName { get; set; }
    public string DriveModel { get; set; }
    public string DriveSN { get; set; }
    public string OldDriveSN { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string Gateway { get; set; }
    public string Hardware { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: If its any consolation, it was not really clear to me how to ask it... :-)  What I'm doing is displaying a page with information on it that includes some of the current devices info. What I was asking was, how to compare the IP Address that the CodeBeyond provided, and sift thru all of the results within the Database, and return all the fields related to that IP. (Found in Device table under IP)  Is that clearer, or do I need to provide more info?

Comment: Seems like your simply looking for the `FirstOrDefault()` method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
Device device = devicesResult.Find(data => data.IP == capturedHostName.Text);
```

This should get you the Device Class with `IP` from your `localHostName`.

Comment: I'm thankful to the community for the prompt help... So this will filter the results from httpclient query, and find the IP that matches capturedHostName.Text?  Let me try that out... :-)

Comment: This is the Results I get back... device = "null" devicesResults = "Count = 2" IP = "10.0.0.4".... It never shows me the rest of the data from row in SQL that contained the IP above. If I search for any of the other values from the above Model they are all "null". So, how do I get back all the results from a Row that has the matching IP of localHostName

Comment: @ekgcorp That's purely up to your API query. Usually the way this scenario is handled is not on client side retrieving full data but on server side passing exact IP that you need the result for.